# How to check if there is any payload (POST) data in a request with hapijs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, hapi.js

This is what I have:

```
server.route({
        method: 'POST',
        path: '/somePath/',
        config: {
          payload:{
                output: 'stream'
            }
        });
```

I expect a short XML and that is why I using 'stream' instead of 'data'. I am using [FakeToe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/faketoe) as the XML parser as it is stream based and in my handler function I call `request.payload.pipe(parser)`. All I want to check is if there is any POST data in the request and if not send a bad request back to the user.

I have thought about getting the size of data in the `request.payload` stream but there does not seem to be straightforward of doing that without pulling first and then pushing back data into the stream, which I don't like.

Everything works perfectly when the data is there, but if not FakeToe does not call the callback function with an error saying that the stream is empty. Also, I do not want to call `request.payload.read` method myself just to check if there is any data.

Any way to do that in hapijs?

Comment: I suppose that you have `content-length` header ?  You could check that from `request.headers` instead of reading the payload

Comment: @tgo Thanks for this simple solution! I guess I need to go thru HTTP basics! Add this as an answer and I will accept it!

Comment: glad it helped. I made it an answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you have `content-length header` ? You could check that from `request.headers` instead of reading the payload.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Joi](https://github.com/hapijs/joi#validatevalue-schema-options-callback) to validate the presence of a payload. It is a schema and validation module provided by Hapi. It will automatically validate any requests received at an endpoint and reply with an appropriate badRequest message if the validation fails.

```
var Joi = require('Joi');

server.route({
        method: 'POST',
        path: '/somePath/',
        config: {
          payload:{
                output: 'stream'
            }
          validate: {
                payload: Joi.any().required()
            }
        });
```

More about this [here](http://hapijs.com/api#route-options) and [here](http://vawks.com/blog/2014/03/22/the-joi-of-validation/).

EDIT:

As per the discussion in this GitHub [Issue](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/issues/472), a validation object like

```
Joi.object({
    pipe: Joi.func().required()
}).unknown();
```

Can be used to test whether the payload is actually a stream.

Comment: Joi validation as suggested by you would work as well, but I believe, for my purpose tgo's solution of using `content-length` is much cleaner and simpler.